# What determines whether admin toolbar is shown to a logged-in user?

Tags: admin, user-roles, capabilities, admin-bar

By default, Wordpress shows admin toolbar to Administrator, Editor, or Author but not to Subscriber or unauthenticated visitors.

What determines whether admin toolbar is shown a logged-in user? I am wondering if it works based on Role, a specific Capability, or something else. I tried to dig in Wordpress core source code to find out but I could not get any clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The admin toolbar is displayed for all users, including Subscribers.

If it's not appearing on your site, then you are likely be using a plugin that changes this behaviour. For example, WooCommerce hides the admin bar from users who do not have the `edit_posts` or `manage_woocommerce`, capability. They have a support article on disabling this behaviour [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/allowing-customer-access-to-wp-admin-and-enabling-the-admin-bar/).

Other plugins, such as membership plugins, might do something similar. You would need to check them individually.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the helpful advice, Jacob!